# Have a submit button run a .rb file using a field from the form (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, submit

I'm trying to create a submit button that will call a ruby script and execute it (the script takes an isbn and pings a third party site and returns  information based on the input). Specifically, I have a form for creating a new book, and the main field I need from the user is the isbn. Upon the submit, I would like to take that isbn and run my ruby script to retrieve the data and show it on the next page. I've tried transferring the .rb code into a helper method, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, and I don't know how I'd change the function of the submit button to execute either the method or the script
This is my helper method

```
module PagesHelper
require 'httpclient'
require 'nokogiri'
def search(hash)

#class SearchBook

#def initialize(isbn)
# @isbn = isbn
#end  


#puts "Enter ISBN: "
#isbn = gets.chomp
#def run
isbn = hash

conditions = ['Acceptable', 'BrandNew', 'Good', 'LikeNew', 'VeryGood']
client = HTTPClient.new
uri = 'https://svcs.ebay.com/services/half/HalfFindingService/v1?OPERATION-    NAME=findHalfItems&REST-PAYLOAD'

count=0
conditions.each do |condition|

query = {
        'X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME' => 'HalfFindingService',
        'SERVICE-VERSION' => '1.0.0',
        'GLOBAL-ID' => 'EBAY-US',
        'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME' => 'Compassi-3b25-406b-b3d6-d69ca7353053',
        'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'XML',
        'productID' => isbn,
        'productID.@type' => 'ISBN',
        'itemFilter' => 'Condition',
        'itemFilter.name' => 'Condition',
        'itemFilter.value' => condition,
        'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' => '3',
        'sortBy' => 'FixedPrice',
        'sortBy.sortOn' => 'FixedPrice',
        'sortBy.sortOrder' => 'INCREASING'
        }

  results = client.get_content(uri, query)
  count += 1
  doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(results)

  if count <= 1
    puts "Book Details"
    puts "--Title: "+doc.css("title").text
    puts "--Author: "+doc.css("nameValueList/value").text
    puts "Prices by Condition:"
  end

  puts "Condition: #{condition}"
  prices = doc.css("price")
  prices.each do |price|
    puts "$#{price.text}"
  end

end

#return count

#end

#end

end
end
```

I'm using the standard form, model, and controller for a Book (which has an isbn) generated from rails generate scaffold Book isbn:string condition:string title:string...

Comment: Is there a reason you are not processing the request in your controller?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to do that is the problem. I'm unsure of where/how I might adapt this code into the current project

Comment: Maybe you could use an after_create call that will contact eBay, get the info about the book and then update the Book entry in your DB. This implies that the changes may not be seen right after you created the book.

Comment: The problem is that we are not putting this information from the third-party site into a database. We want to display that data, and that's the only time we want to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. It may not have been the best way, but it worked. 
My final file was it's own file called search, made as an active ruby file

```
<% conditions = ['BrandNew', 'LikeNew', 'VeryGood', 'Good', 'Acceptable' ]%>
<% client = HTTPClient.new %>
<% uri = 'https://svcs.ebay.com/services/half/HalfFindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findHalfItems&REST-PAYLOAD'%>

<%count=0%>

<%isbn = params[:isbn] %>
<% conditions.each do |condition| %>

<% query = {
       'X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME' => 'HalfFindingService',
       'SERVICE-VERSION' => '1.0.0',
       'GLOBAL-ID' => 'EBAY-US',
       'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME' => 'Compassi-3b25-406b-b3d6-d69ca7353053',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'XML',
       'productID' => isbn,
       'productID.@type' => 'ISBN',
       'itemFilter' => 'Condition',
       'itemFilter.name' => 'Condition',
       'itemFilter.value' => condition,
       'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' => '3',
       'sortBy' => 'FixedPrice',
       'sortBy.sortOn' => 'FixedPrice',
       'sortBy.sortOrder' => 'INCREASING'
       } %>

<% results = client.get_content(uri, query) %>
<% count += 1 %>
<% doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(results) %>

<p>
<% if count <= 1 %>
<b><%= "Book Details" %></b>
<br>
<i><%= "--Title:"+doc.css("title").text %></i>
<br>
<i><%= "--Author: "+doc.css("nameValueList/value").text %></i>
<br>
<br>
<b><%= "Prices by Condition:" %></b>
<br>
<br>
<% end %>

<b><%= "Condition: #{condition}" %></b>
<br>
<%  prices = doc.css("price") %>
<%  prices.each do |price| %>
<%=   "$#{price.text}" %>
<br>
<% end %>

</p>

<% end %>
```

And then in my index for listing books, I just had a separate link used for checking the prices:

```
<%=link_to 'Check Prices', controller: "pages", :action => "search", :isbn=> book.isbn%>
```

Thanks for all of the help anyway! I didn't get exactly what I wanted to do done, but we have now a working page.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by creating a separate model class that encapsulates the call to ebay. Something like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # existing model code

  def price_information
    @price_information ||= PriceInformation.new(self)
  end
end

class PriceInformation
  def initialize(book)
    get_price_information(book.isbn)
  end

  def get_price_information(isbn)
    # use your script and set accessors appropriately
  end
end
```

In your view, on the show page (I.e. after the create), you can then simply do book.price_information to retrieve the relevant info and use it in your view.